# Domain of $\operatorname{arccos}(x-1)$

Tags: trigonometry

All we know that domain of $\operatorname{arccos}(a)$ is $[-1; 1]$. So, if $a = x - 1$, then $-1 \leq x - 1 \leq 1$. I substracted one from all parts and got $-2\leq x\leq0$. But the answer is $[0;2]$. Where is mistake?

Comment: $-1 - 1 \neq 0$

Comment: Note that you are finding the **domain** of $\arccos(x-1)$, not the range,

Comment: From your question, as it was pointed by other users, we can deduce, that there should be domain, not range, here, If such is your intention, we will correct it.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

You have two inequalities:
$$
-1\le x-1 \quad \land \quad x-1\le1
$$
solve separately and you find:
$$
-1+1 \le x \quad \land \quad x\le 1+1
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: **Add** 1 to sides of the inequalities.

Comment: I realized $a$ in $x-a$ there equals to $1$

Answer (score -1):

The range of $arccos(x-1)$ is the same as the range of $arccosx$ which is $[0,\pi]$ It seems like you are confused with the domain of $arccos(x-1)$ which can be found by solving the inequality stated by others...

Comment: Hey, a downvote, but without an explanation? What is wrong with my answer?